# Windows 8 App Navigation Design

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I want to create a windows 8 app with level of detail equal with 3.

I think about creating a Flat system where some of my pages will have Hierarchical system. 
(More about this here ---> [Msdn Navigation Design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761500))

I must implement the following type of navigation: Content --> European Laws ---> Decisions ---> Decision nr. 155.

Can this navigation design pass the Windows Store Check?

If you know any accepted template with level of detail equal with 3, i'm open for recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First a disclaimer: I don't evaluate apps for the Windows store, and so I can't speak for what a Windows Store reviewer will or won't accept.*

That said, I'm not aware of any concrete rule that you can't have more than three levels.  The motivation behind "no more than three levels" is that the user not get lost in the midst of his or her navigation. From what I can see, you have a fairly clear hierarchy of information here and one that I'd say is in the spirit of the design guidelines.

If you do want to explore other options, take a look at apps with similarly hierarchical domains that are in the store now.  Perhaps recipe apps?  Another resource, though I haven't perused them all, are [the Windows 8 Design templates on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/win8templates).  I'm not sure if any of them go to more than three levels, but they may spark some navigation or design alternatives for you.

Comment: I think about having an application with 3 pages , where 1 page has a grid template(which has 3 levels). I search throught Design templates on CodePlex and i didnt find any template using this design . Throught the store too .

Comment: The recipe apps and the news apps have flat system combined with hierarchical . Example : they have 3 pages , where 1 page have 2 levels in hierarchy . I want to know if i can extend this to 3 pages where 1 page have 3 levels in hierarchy . Thanks for your answer .